# Please explain for the below PHP OOPS code execution

Tags: php

Please explain execution flow of the below statement

```
$this->setPageID()
    ->paginate()
    ->sendCacheHeaders();
```

in below code

```
protected function main()
    {
       $this->setPageID()
            ->paginate()
            ->sendCacheHeaders();
}

  public function setPageID()
    {
        $this->pageID = (int)$this->Router->getRealPageID();

        return $this;
    }

  protected function paginate()
    {
        d('paginating with $this->pagerPath: ' . $this->pagerPath);
        $Paginator = Paginator::factory($this->Registry);
        $Paginator->paginate($this->Cursor, $this->PER_PAGE,
            array('currentPage' => $this->pageID,
                  'path'        => '{_WEB_ROOT_}/' . $this->pagerPath));

        $this->pagerLinks = $Paginator->getLinks();

        return $this;
    }

 protected function sendCacheHeaders()
    {


        return $this;
    }
```

What is the flow of this methods execution?, Is there any data transfer/communication b/w these methods?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call this chaining. Basically, your functions are part of a class and that class has an instance (`$class = new class()`).

Your functions are returning that instance. While not a best practice per se, it does mean that you can chain the calls back to back.

```
 $this->setPageID() ->paginate() ->sendCacheHeaders();
```

Note how each function returns `$this`. So it's the same as writing

```
$this->setPageID(); 
$this->paginate();
$this->sendCacheHeaders();
```

They're not communicating with each other explicitly. They all belong to the same class instance so they can access any variables belonging to that class (or any parent classes). So when `paginate()` sets `$this->pagerLinks`, any function in that class can access that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this
    ->setPageID()         // sets class variable $pageID from Router class. Returns current class.
    ->paginate()          // Setup of Paginator class, assigns links to $pagerLinks. Returns current class
    ->sendCacheHeaders(); // does nothing. Returns current class
```

Because every function return `$this` so it's possible to chain method calls. Without returning `$this` your call will look like this:

```
$this->setPageID();
$this->paginate();
$this->sendCacheHeaders();
```